# Help with strange type of bolt

Tags: bolts

I'm hoping someone can help me identify what type of bolt(if it is even a bolt) this is, what it is used for and most importantly how to remove it.

This is used to attached a boat engine to a transom, there are three other normal bolts (one in the bottom of one of the pictures).

[image: Front of bolt]

[image: back of bolt]

Comment: could be some type of a security device, similar to the kind on expensive automobile wheels

Comment: @jsotola you are correct, it is to prevent the bolt from being removed without a key, I will add an answer and some pictures later.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be a carriage bolt, but it's impossible to tell for sure.  Take the nut off the inside, hit the bolt with a mallet and see what happens.

Edit based on addition of interior photo...

I wonder if that big black cylinder is some type of damper intended absorb shock and vibration.  Maybe the one on the other side failed and they replaced it with a regular bolt.  You might try a channellock pliers or such to take it off (if that's your goal).  Or post this to a boat forum and see if anybody has a better answer.

Comment: I think so too. It looks like a common carriage bolt with a proprietary retainer underneath it. The rusty galvanized bit hooks over the transom to prevent the bolt from rotating when the nut is tightened.

Comment: I dont see any nut on the inside, I've updated the inside picture link